# MySQL Fulltext Search ORDER BY column

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

This question MAY have been asked before, but I can't for the life of me find the answer.

In order to avoid

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE name LIKE '%searchphrase%' ORDER BY score
```

which, as I understand it, will never use index and will always use filesort there's the ability to use **FULLTEXT** index.

The question: How can I order by score without a filesort if I perform a fulltext search?

Answer (score 0):

Result rows will come out in whatever order they're in in the FULLTEXT index which certainly isn't the order required by `ORDER BY score`, so the fulltext matches need to be sorted for `ORDER BY` in a separate step, and this is what `filesort` does.

The only alternative execution plan would be to retrieve rows in `score` order, and then apply fulltext match row by row, which totally defies any fulltext specific optimizations.

What may make sense in your case may be to have a combined index on `(score, name)` and stick with `LIKE` if your search expression covers a large part of the student rows, in this case you'd get an index scan in `score` order and the `LIKE` expression can be evaluated on index entries. Sou you're getting a full index scan instead of a full table scan, and no extra sort is needed as index entries are ordered by `score` already.

But if the number of matching rows is rather small compared to the total number of rows in the table doing a fulltext index lookup first, followed by filesort, will be the better plan.

Comment: Thank you indeed for the answer but can it really be the way to go, to use a filesort? That has gotten my server to get a lot of open tables and the memory consumption is going through the roof. The very poor man's solution I'm currently using is index on (score, name) and using LIKE 'phrase%' which allows use of index but it is sooooo sub-par and not what my users expect when using the search.